# How to do basic authentication in Yii2 REST api

Tags: rest, yii

I have tried this, but it does not help me: [Yii2 REST API BasicAuth not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597095/yii2-rest-api-basicauth-not-working)

Here is what I did:

I have BaseController and DocumentController extending it.

in BaseController I have this code:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ]
    ];

    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
        'auth' => [$this, 'authenticate']
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}

/**
 * Finds user by username and password
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @param string $password
 * @return static|null
 */
public function authenticate($username, $password) 
{
    // username, password are mandatory fields
    if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
        return null;
    }

    // get user using requested email
    $user = User::findByUsername($username);

    // if no record matching the requested user
    if(empty($user)) {
        return null;
    }

    // if password validation fails
    if(!User::validatePassword($password)) {
        return null;
    }

    // if user validates (both user_email, user_password are valid)
    return $user;
}
```

When I try to visit my api: `localhost/api/documents/5`
I get this error: `Getting unknown property: app\\controllers\\DocumentController::password_hash`

What I am supposed to do to make this thing work ? I just do not understand what yii wants from me anymore.

EDIT: full error :

```
{"name":"Unknown Property","message":"Getting unknown property: app\\controllers\\DocumentController::password_hash","code":0,"type":"yii\\base\\UnknownPropertyException","file":"/var/www/html/api/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php","line":143,"stack-trace":["#0 /var/www/html/api/_protected/models/UserIdentity.php(129): yii\\base\\Component->__get('password_hash')","#1 /var/www/html/api/_protected/controllers/AppController.php(58): app\\models\\UserIdentity->validatePassword('wspass')","#2 [internal function]: app\\controllers\\AppController->authenticate('wsuser', 'wspass')","#3 /var/www/html/api/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/auth/HttpBasicAuth.php(68): call_user_func(Array, 'wsuser', 'wspass')","#4 /var/www/html/api/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/auth/AuthMethod.php(60): yii\\filters\\auth\\HttpBasicAuth->authenticate(Object(yii\\web\\User), Object(yii\\web\\Request), Object(yii\\web\\Response))","#5 /var/www/html/api/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ActionFilter.php(71): yii\\filters\\auth\\AuthMethod->beforeAction(Object(yii\\rest\\IndexAction))","#6 [internal function]: yii\\base\\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\\base\\ActionEvent))","#7 /var/www/html/api/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(541): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\\base\\ActionEvent))","#8 /var/www/html/api/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(269): yii\\base\\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\\base\\ActionEvent))","#9 /var/www/html/api/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php(108): yii\\base\\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\\rest\\IndexAction))","#10 /var/www/html/api/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(152): yii\\web\\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\\rest\\IndexAction))","#11 /var/www/html/api/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(454): yii\\base\\Controller->runAction('index', Array)","#12 /var/www/html/api/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(84): yii\\base\\Module->runAction('document/index', Array)","#13 /var/www/html/api/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\\web\\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\\web\\Request))","#14 /var/www/html/api/index.php(12): yii\\base\\Application->run()","#15 {main}"]}
```

Comment: please write full error message.

Comment: you should search relevant files for `password_hash`.

Comment: @mohit ; I have updated post with full error. But I do not understand why yii is complaining about password_hash in DocumentController.

Comment: According to error message you are accessing password_hash as a DocumentController property but it isn't defined in this controller. 
check if you have written `$this->password_hash` kind a code in controller coz $this represent Controller class. It should be accessed by $model class object.

Comment: you might also want to check in this file too - 
`var/www/html/api/_protected/models/UserIdentity.php(129)`